# Perform async operation on app exit in React Native

Tags: react-native

My application requires the data in redux store to be persisted on app exit, I am looking for a proper way to do this.

I tried persisting data on componentWillUnmount of root component but it did not work. It looks like the process is killed before persistence is completed.

I also tried if AppState could be of any use. It does give information about the background/foreground status of the application, but it did not help either

Of course, I can update by persistence on every update of store, but I think there must be a better solution.

Comment: The reality is that there is very little you can count on on mobile devices, since anything can happen - the battery runs out (or the user actually removes it), the OS shuts down your process, or some other process takes precedence.

Because of this, it might be actually better to save as soon as you can, even if this is not as "efficient" as doing it once the app closes.

Comment: Have you tried `redux persist`? https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist